# I am trying to count values in a spilled array that are not blank or NA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table where I have created a unique list using

```
=UNIQUE(IF(Name1="A",Name2,""),FALSE,FALSE)
```

The resulting list is a spillover array and has a blank space at the top (for the false if results) and a `#N/A`  at the bottom (Not sure why, but not super important).

I would like to then count the unique list, while ignoring the blank at the top and the `#N/A` at the bottom. As of now I am just using `=COUNTA(J3#)-2`, but is there a way to either filter the count or filter the unique function to remove those two?

For reference `=Count(J3#)` returns `0` which is why I am using `=CountA`

I considered an `=IFNA` function to make the `NA` also a `""` but that doesn't remove the space from the count. It could possibly simplify a filter function though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example one could try, one may need to adjust the ranges/cell references as per their suit:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D16</kbd>

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(C16:C20,IFNA(C16:C20,"")<>""))<>""))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(C16:C20,IFERROR((C16:C20,"")<>""))<>""))
```

---

Instead of using `COUNTA()` or `ROWS()` function it is better to use `SUM()` because even if there is no data then the `SUM()` will return `0` whereas the rest shall return error which needs using again `IFERROR()` function.

---

To explain further:

- Using `IFNA()` or `IFERROR()` function to coerce the error values as `empty`
- Next, Using `FILTER()` function to take only those which are not empty using within the **`include`** parameter of the said function as
  `IFERROR((C16:C20,"")<>""` which returns `TRUE` and `FALSE`s, `FILTER()` function grabs only those which are `TRUE` and returns the output with all the duplicates.
- Wrapping within `UNIQUE()` Function to get the unique values.
- Lastly, wrapping within a `SUM()` function before checking the returned array is not blank`

---

In context of the OP, the formula will be :

```
=LET(arr, IF(Name1="A",Name2,""), SUM(--(UNIQUE(FILTER(arr, IFERROR(arr,"")<>""))<>""))
```

---

The above formula can be improved more if some mock ups/sample data is produced in the OP.

---